# How can I solve this circular dependency? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, frontend

I have the next problem: I had been creating a webpage for search GIFs using GIPHY API, everything was going OK until I had to implement a functionality to add GIFs to favorites, the favorites are stored in local storage and they are shown in a separate HTML file using CSS grid. I can add and delete favorites without problems outside /favorites.html, and I can also add favorites from trending GIFs inside this url, the problem is that when I need to remove a favorite and I am on /favorites.html I want the grid to be created from zero and therefore the user will see the gif disappear.

For that function I've created a GIFCard class which allow me to create all the HTML elements for a card and add all the classes they need to look fine using css styles, also this class handles the events so it automatically adds event listeners to all the buttons. I have a file called favoritesPage.js which defines a function called showAllUntilOffset() this function is used whenever the user press the favorite button for a GIF Card and is seeing favorites its work is to create again the GIF grid so it will be updated but I also need to import the GIFCard class in favoritesPage.js to create the Card object, add the html classes and add the event listener.

[image: Cannot access before initialization]

Here is an image of my webpage working correctly, it just stops working when I import "showAllUntilOffset" from favoritesPage.js because of the circular dependency (I guess).

[image: Webpage working]

Next is the code for my favoritesPage.js file and the GIFCard class, constructor and other methods that are not relevant to the problem are not shown here.

favoritesPage.js:

```js
import { GIFCard as Card } from "../entities/GIFCard.js";

import { favoriteGIFs } from "../favorites.js";

import {
  favoritesGrid,
  favoritesEmpty,
  favoritesShow,
  seeMoreFavorites,
} from "../dom/favoritesSelectors.js";

import { displayComponent, hideComponent } from "../utils/utils.js";

function createAndAddFavGIFCards(start, end) {
  for (let i = start; i < end; i += 1) {
    const newCard = new Card(
      favoriteGIFs[i].id,
      favoriteGIFs[i].title,
      favoriteGIFs[i].username,
      favoriteGIFs[i].url,
      favoriteGIFs[i].fixedHeightURL,
      i,
      "Favorite GIF"
    );

    if (window.innerWidth >= 1280) {
      favoritesGrid.append(newCard.createCardDesktop());
    } else {
      favoritesGrid.append(newCard.createCardMobile());
    }
  }
}

function loadAndShowFavorites() {
  favoritesGrid.innerHTML = "";

  if (favoriteGIFs.length === 0) {
    displayComponent(favoritesEmpty);
  } else {
    displayComponent(favoritesShow);

    let limit = favoriteGIFs.length >= 12 ? 12 : favoriteGIFs.length;

    if (favoriteGIFs.length > 12) {
      displayComponent(seeMoreFavorites);
    }

    createAndAddFavGIFCards(0, limit);
  }
}

export function showAllUntilOffset() {
  favoritesGrid.innerHTML = "";

  if (favoriteGIFs.length === 0) {
    displayComponent(favoritesEmpty);
    hideComponent(favoritesShow);
  }

  if (favoriteGIFs.length <= 12) {
    hideComponent(seeMoreFavorites);
    offset = favoriteGIFs.length;
  } else if (favoriteGIFs.length < offset) {
    offset -= 1;
  }

  createAndAddFavGIFCards(0, offset);
}

function getOffsetAndUpdateBtn() {
  start = offset;

  if (offset + 12 <= favoriteGIFs.length) {
    offset += 12;
  } else {
    const excess = favoriteGIFs.length - offset;
    offset += excess;
  }

  if (offset === favoriteGIFs.length) {
    hideComponent(seeMoreFavorites);
  }
}

let start;
let offset = 12;

loadAndShowFavorites();

seeMoreFavorites.addEventListener("click", () => {
  getOffsetAndUpdateBtn();

  createAndAddFavGIFCards(start, offset);
});
```

GIFCard Class:

```js
import { showAllUntilOffset } from "../favorites/favoritesPage.js";

export class GIFCard {
  createCardDesktop() {
    const card = document.createElement("div");
    card.classList.add("card");

    const overlay = document.createElement("div");
    overlay.classList.add("overlay");

    const text = this.createCardInfo();

    const favoriteBtn = this.createCardButton("favorite", "card-btn");
    this.favoriteBtn = favoriteBtn;

    const downloadBtn = this.createCardButton("download", "card-btn");
    this.downloadBtn = downloadBtn;

    const expandBtn = this.createCardButton("expand", "card-btn");
    this.expandBtn = expandBtn;

    const gifImg = this.createCardImg();
    gifImg.classList.add("card-img");

    card.append(overlay, text, favoriteBtn, downloadBtn, expandBtn, gifImg);

    this.htmlDesktopCard = card;

    this.checkAndUpdateFavBtn();
    this.expandGIFDesktopEventListener();
    this.addFavoriteEventListener();

    return card;
  }

  favEventAction() {
    if (!seeingFavorites()) {
      if (!this.isInFavorites()) {
        this.pushToFavorites();
      } else {
        this.removeFromFavorites();
      }
    } else {
      if (!this.isInFavorites()) {
        this.pushToFavorites();

        if (this.type === "Trending GIF") {
          hideComponent(favoritesEmpty);
          displayComponent(favoritesShow);

          if (window.innerWidth >= 1280) {
            favoritesGrid.append(this.createCardDesktop());
          } else {
            favoritesGrid.append(this.createCardMobile());
          }
        }
      } else {
        this.removeFromFavorites();

        if (this.type === "Favorite GIF") {
          showAllUntilOffset();
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  addFavoriteEventListener() {
    this.favoriteBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.favEventAction();
    });
  }
}
```

Hope you can help me, I've tried everything and I just can't figure out a solution. This is my first JavaScript big project so if you can recommend me good practices I'd really appreciate it. **Thank you so much.**

Comment: Solutions: a) import the other module instead (fragile) b) move the `let start; let offset = 12; loadAndShowFavorites(); …` code into your main module, and import the modules (with their circular dependency) there or c) remove the import and instead pass `showAllUntilOffset`  as a parameter to your card constructor.

Comment: That did the trick, specifically solution c). Thank you so much.